# I can't find a way to evade a Value Error using data from dataframe in sklearn pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to run some basic machine learning algorithms on numerical data (floats) and am having issues getting the data to be read in. I using python 2.7, sklearn, pandas, and working through jupyter (ipython notebook). As a first pass I was trying to use a basic random forest search, however when using the functions I keep getting ValueError.

The data was read into a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_table("p12.dat", delim_whitespace=True)
```

[screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCVFb.png)

[image]

df.dtypes shows that all values of interest are float64.

Using a basic expression:

```
def classification_model(model, data, predictors, outcome):
  model.fit(data[predictors],data[outcome])
  predictions = model.predict(data[predictors])
  accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(predictions,data[outcome])
  print "Accuracy : %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(accuracy)
  print "Cross-Validation Score : %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(np.mean(error))
  model.fit(data[predictors],data[outcome])
```

and then setting the variables and executing:

```
outcome_var = 'ki'
predictor_var = ['Etot','TSs','Eww-nbr']
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
classification_model(model, df,predictor_var,outcome_var)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-7dd611cce611> in <module>()
----> 1 classification_model(model, df,predictor_var,outcome_var)

<ipython-input-8-956e572db2f4> in classification_model(model, data, predictors, outcome)
      1 def classification_model(model, data, predictors, outcome):
      2   #Fit the model:
----> 3   model.fit(data[predictors],data[outcome].values)
      4 
      5   #Make predictions on training set:

/Users/jonathangough/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    233         self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]
    234 
--> 235         y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
    236 
    237         if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:

/Users/jonathangough/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.pyc in _validate_y_class_weight(self, y)
    419 
    420     def _validate_y_class_weight(self, y):
--> 421         check_classification_targets(y)
    422 
    423         y = np.copy(y)

/Users/jonathangough/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.pyc in check_classification_targets(y)
    171     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput', 
    172             'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 173         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)
    174 
    175 

ValueError: Unknown label type: array([[  2.72000000e+00],
       [  4.60000000e+00],
       [  6.70000000e+00],
       [  2.30000000e+00],
       [  1.70000000e+00],
       [  2.20000000e+00],
       [  3.60000000e+00],
       [  9.10000000e+00],
```

I have searched and googled, but I can't figure out what to do. My understanding was that one could use floats in a random forest algorithm (so I didn't think that was the error).

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try using the numpy arrays that underlie pandas as the input for sklearn model. I see in your code you do not have .values for data[predictors], data[outcome], whereas in your stacktrace you do have data[outcome].values. Try making sure all of the inputs have '.values'

Answer (score 1):

In scikit-learn, a Classifier predicts a discrete variable, i.e. the data type of the target variable must be either integer or string. If you are trying to model a continuous variable, you must use a "regressor" model, in your case the equivalent model is `RandomForestRegresser`.